# How SharePoint 2013 built-en ranking models works?

Tags: 2013, fast-search

I want to understand how SharePoint 2013 built-en ranking models works. I tried to search it over web but I don't see any documentation that describe these models.

Here is the list of ranking models that are available in SharePoint 2013:

1. Default Ranking Model
2. Catalog ranking Model
3. Recommender ranking model
4. People Search expertise social distance ranking model
5. People Search name social distance ranking model
6. People Search name ranking model
7. Popularity ranking model
8. People search application ranking model
9. People Search social distance model
10. People Search expertise ranking model
11. Site Suggestion  ranking model
12. Search model With Boosted Minspan
13. O14 Default ranking model
14. Search Model Without Minspan

Comment: you can try follow that guy (http://powersearching.wordpress.com), he might be able to answer some questions :) however I don't expect any comprehensive documentation on this topic exists

Answer (score 5):

Please refer to the following blog post which described basics of sharepoint 2013 ranking models.

http://powersearching.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/how-sharepoint-2013-ranking-models-work/

Please let me know which model are you interested in, I will cover this in following posts.